# Render helper in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to have a helper method for my phoenix templates which renders the navigation. In my views directory I have added the following function

```
def render("breadcrumbs.html", %{user: user}) do
    "<div>nav goes here</div>"
end
```

when I call this render function it shows up as a string and not rendered HTML. How should I create a helper function which can be used on all views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EEx in Phoenix by default will escape all content that's inserted using `<%= ... %>` to prevent XSS attacks. You can mark a string as being safe for inserting without any escaping using `Phoenix.HTML.raw/1`. So, in your helper function, you should do this instead:

```
def render("breadcrumbs.html", %{user: user}) do
  raw("<div>nav goes here</div>")
end
```

Make sure to only use this if you trust the HTML. You should not call `raw` on arbitrary user input without some kind of sanitization.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a generic place for all eex files to access?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "generic place for all eex files to access"..